# WCF Service in Console app throwing error

Tags: wcf, binding, console-application, wcf-hosting

**BasicHttp and NetTcp Binding hosted in Console App**

I have the below web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloService.HelloService"  behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:59084/"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:59076/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The Interface

```
namespace HelloService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        String GetMessage(String Name);
    }
}
```

Class that extends Interface

```
 using System.ServiceModel;
    namespace HelloService
    {
        public class HelloService : IHelloService
        {
            public string GetMessage(string Name)
            {
                return "Hello " + Name;
            }
        }
    }
```

and Console App code for hosting

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace HelloServiceHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using(ServiceHost host  = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService.HelloService)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Host Started");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting below error when i try to run the Console app

```
HTTP could not register URL http://+:8080/. Your process does not have
access rights to this namespace (see
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).
```

- I tried other port number like 53895, thinking port 8080 might be pre occupied. No Luck!!
- When i browsed for this error, i came to know this problem due to my
  account being non admin. Now my doubt is WCFTest Client also execued
  under my account itself. How can it run the similar code and i can't?

  Also, any suggestions to make this work would be appriciated. May be
  something to do with Webconfig again??

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: In your question you are telling about web.config, but in console app you should have app.config

Comment: @Uriil : Sorry mate, its the app.config file itself. Thank you

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885744/wcf-servicehost-access-rights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks alright. I tried it and it works.
Try the solution here: [HTTP could not register URL http://+:8000/HelloWCF/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727293/http-could-not-register-url-http-8000-hellowcf-your-process-does-not-have)

It basically tells you to close your Visual Studio IDE and open it by doing a right-click "Run as administrator"

Comment: i cannot run VS IDE in admin mode, i dont have the admin rights. Ihave accepted the answer, just looking if i can get any work around for the same. Thank you mate

Comment: @Ramu, sorry that you are still having the problem. If you can prove it to them that this is causing you the issue, they may ease of on the admin rights.

Comment: Yeah make sense mate. i was just testing the app. Actually i need to host it in IIS. just testing around byu hosting it in console app. Thank you :)